# Creating a plot from random sample with mean and standard deviation

Tags: r

> Repeat the following 10 times and calculate the mean each time: sample
> 30 observations from a normally-distributed population having mean 0
> and standard deviation 2. Create a data.frame containing the output
> from the 10 simulations and generate a single plot demonstrating the
> mean and st.dev of each of 10 samples.

I am a complete beginner and don't know where to go from here:

```
tensample <- replicate(10, rnorm(30, mean = 0, sd = 2))
tensampleDF <- data.frame(tensample)
```

I know I can find the mean and sd of each of the samples like so:

```
means <- colMeans(tensampleDF)
sd <- apply(tensampleDF, 2, sd)
```

But how to plot them together?

Comment: Hint: You've already created a data.frame in one of the previous lines you've posted. To plot the ``means`` and ``sd`` together, you need to do this again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I need to do what again?

Comment: To plot them together, you need to create a `data.frame` with one column as ``sd`` and one column as ``mean``. You've already created a (different) `data.frame` in a previous line (but created it with one column rather than two), so you just need to do the same thing again with two columns.

Comment: My data.frame has 10 columns - one for each sample. I tried adding in sd and mean as new columns and new rows (separately) but I don't know how to plot them in an intelligible way.

Answer (score 1):

This will off course depend on which graphics system ist meant to be used. This is a way for base graphics:

```
tensample <- replicate(10, rnorm(30, mean = 0, sd = 2))
tensampleDF <- data.frame(tensample)

m <- colMeans(tensampleDF)
upper <- m + apply(tensampleDF, 2, sd)
lower <- m - apply(tensampleDF, 2, sd)

plot(1:10, colMeans(tensampleDF), pch = 15, ylim = c(-5, 5),
     xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
arrows(x0 =1:10, x1 = 1:10, y0 = lower, y1 = upper, length = 0)
```

It will produce something like

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to use ggplot2 for most things but at this point I don't even care.

Comment: I'm getting an error with this: Error in arrows(x0 = 1:10, x1 = 1:10, y0 = lower, y1 = upper, length = 0) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: `plot` is called in the line above `arrows` and that should include the call to `plot.new`. Try running the whole code snipped I posted and look closely, where the *first* error or warning happens.

Comment: I added an additional answer using `ggplot2` - it seemed sensible to keep those in different answers.

Comment: Thanks, it was just a miss-click earlier causing the error. You've been a huge help!

Comment: If so, please consider accepting the answer as described in https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This is a ggplot2 answer

```
tensample <- replicate(10, rnorm(30, mean = 0, sd = 2))
tensampleDF <- data.frame(tensample)
m = colMeans(tensampleDF)

d <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                m = m,
                upper = m + apply(tensampleDF, 2, sd),
                lower = m - apply(tensampleDF, 2, sd))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=id, y=m, ymin=lower, ymax = upper))
```

[image]

You should correct the x-axis stops etc but now your are free to choose the graphics system.

**Edit:**

In order to achieve acceptable axes maybe do something more along the lines of

```
ggplot(d) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=id, y=m, ymin=lower, ymax = upper)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, minor_breaks = NULL) +
  xlab("x") +
  ylab("y") + 
  theme_bw()
```